# Import a MIDI drum track into a Digitech RP255 multi effects pedal?

Tags: midi, effects-pedal

I just got a Digitech RP255 multi effects pedal with a built in drum machine. Is there any way to import a MIDI drum track into the pedal?  There are around 90 or so drum track samples built in, and I was wondering if it'd be possible to add on to that by importing ones we download off the internet.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to import new patters or MIDI into the RP255's drum machine.

ftp://ftp.digitech.com/pub/pdfs/Manuals/RP255/RP255%20Manual%2018-6411V-A.pdf